# How to push to view controller form presented xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, pushviewcontroller

I have xib of passcode and after I tap on login button there will be web service that will call and after success response, I have to present xib of passcode.
When I complete that portion I have to push to another view controller from presented xib.

Here is my code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(unlockWasSuccessfulLockScreenViewController:pincode:)]) {
        [_delegate unlockWasSuccessfulLockScreenViewController:self pincode:pincode];

        PassCodeVC *sgn = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PassCodeVC"];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:sgn];

        [nav pushViewController:sgn animated:YES];

    }
    }];
```

and I have presented xib like this:

```
 JKLLockScreenViewController * viewController = [[JKLLockScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([JKLLockScreenViewController class]) bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[viewController setLockScreenMode:LockScreenModeNew];    // enum { LockScreenModeNormal, LockScreenModeNew, LockScreenModeChange }
[viewController setDelegate:self];
[viewController setDataSource:self];
[viewController setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:53.0 / 255.0 green:115.0 / 255.0  blue:157.0 /255.0  alpha:1]];

[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use current navigation then Just simple pass new controller using current navigation controller.

```
PassCodeVC *sgn = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PassCodeVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: i have done but it say you are passing nil value in navigation controller

Comment: Get StoryBoard Like this:

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    PassCodeVC * sgn = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PassCodeVC"];

also check StoryBoard ID is set or not?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the Storyboard ID of the View Controller you are trying to load. This is located in the inspector, just below where you assign a custom class to your view controller.[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXYJ.png)